# MVC3 EditorFor() Change Value in JavaScript Model Does Not Recognize Changes

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

EDIT:
After looking at the way I'm doing this, I decided to change my whole view model, so this question isn't valid any more.  I wouldn't mind knowing what I was doing wrong, but I really don't need the answer for my project.

Thanks!

I use Javascript to change the value of a text box when the dropdownlist's value is changed.  When the page is posted, the value that was changed in Javascript is always zero.

The Javascript seems to work fine, but the value doesn't make it back to the server.

Here is my view model:

```
...
[Required(ErrorMessage = "\"{0}\" is required")]
    [Display(Name = "Mileage Out")]
    public decimal MileageOut { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Vehicle is required.")]
    public Guid VehicleID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Vehicle")]
    public List<SelectListItem> Vehicles { get; set; }
....
```

Here is my view:

```
....
<div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Vehicles, "Vehicle")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.VehicleID, new SelectList(Model.Vehicles, "Value", "Text"), "Vehicle is required . . .", new {@onchange="GetLastMileage(this.value);"})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Vehicles)
    </div> 

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MileageOut)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MileageOut, null, "txtMileageOut")
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MileageOut)
    </div>
...
<script type="text/javascript">

function GetLastMileage(vehicleID) {
    switch (String(vehicleID))
    {

        @{
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, decimal> item in Model.VehiclesLastMileage)
            {
                @Html.Raw("case '" + item.Key + "': document.getElementById('txtMileageOut').value = '" + ((decimal)item.Value).ToString() + "';break;")
            }
        }
        default: return 0;
    }
}

</script>
```

I have found that if I change this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.MileageOut, null, "txtMileageOut")
```

to this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.MileageOut)
```

the the date gets back to the server fine, but the JavaScript doesn't work (no id on the textbox).  Obviously I'm using the wrong method for changing a value on the client, but I don't know the right one.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Change the javascript.

```
document.getElementById('txtMileageOut').value
```

to

```
document.getElementById('MileageOut').value
```

Also, you should use jQuery and move the javascript out to its own external file. It would also simplify the JS code a lot. You could use classed as selectors instead of ID and do a lot more in less code.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll try this when I get back in.

Comment: This doesn't work.  Firebug says: 'document.getElementById("MileageOut") is null'